# UIL update cached images

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I want to display Facebook profile picture by using [URL](https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=square&height=500&width=500) but whenever user changes his profile picture, this library doesn't update cached image.

My UIL version is 1.9.3, display options:

```
    new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(android.R.color.white)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .build();
```

So how I should check if image in url changed? Or maybe you know another library which have this feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you store facebook ID of the user ?

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIL has multithread image loading (async or sync). See library features on [github](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

You enable caching on disc (device's file system or SD card) `.cacheOnDisk(true)`. Library loads the image from this cache. Disable disc caching `.cacheOnDisk(false)` and write the following code in your Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_preview)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_preview)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_preview)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(false)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .writeDebugLogs()
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayOptions)             
                .build();

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);

    AnimateFirstDisplayListener animate  = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

    imageLoader.displayImage(YourImageURL, userIv, animate);
    ...
}

public static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

    static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```